# Dynamic Views in Layout

Tags: android, android-layout

In my xml i have 3 view at first

i have to hide one view then after that i have to unhide that in program.

When i hide that view the other must adjust and when i unhide it have to adjust

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose you have a layout like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <!-- your content here -->

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout02"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <!-- your content here -->

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout03"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <!-- your content here -->
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

At the starting of your program use

```
LinearLayout linearLayout1,linearLayout2,linearLayout3;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout);
//define and declare  the layouts
                  linearLayout1=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.LinearLayout01);
        linearLayout2=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.LinearLayout02);
        linearLayout3=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.LinearLayout03);

 }
```

Now when you want to  hide the first layout ,use

```
linearLayout1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Now when you want to  show the first layout ,use

```
linearLayout1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

The situation is same for all layouts..

Hope this will help you..