# Dynamically display a TextView

Tags: android, textview

Is it possible to display a `TextView` dynamically so that the height of the text can be retrieved in the middle of the Application but not at the end that is done using `onGlobalLayout()` or `onSizeChanged()`.

My requirement is to display the text in the TextView to a certain height limit. I need to check the height of the text in the TextView so that I can achieve my requirement but using any of the `onGlobalLayout()` or `onSizeChanged()`, I am getting the height at the end which is of no use to me because I can't check at the end.

Is there anyway to achieve my requirement?

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you.

[Dynamic Views in Layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4864556/dynamic-views-in-layout)

Comment: no... i need to get the height of the textview while the application is processing

Comment: then try this tv.getMeasuredHeight() or tv.getHeight() it will give you the height for the textview after its attached in view

Comment: but it is getting attached at the end of the application .. so i cant get the height of the text in the middle ..that is the reason i m searching if i could attach the textview directly after setting the TextView using setText().. is it possible ?

Comment: we can add a textview dynamically in activity by TextView tv=new TextView(myActivity.this); tv.settext("xxx"); lay.add(tv); lay is our layout where we have to add the textview.

Comment: but i cant get the height of the textview using tv.getHeight() because it returns 0 , as the textview is not yet attached